# Excluding columns from a dataframe based on their mean without using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe df and I would like to drop columns which have a mean greater than 10 and less than 2. How can I do it without a loop?

I tried this without a loop

```
df=df.drop(df.mean(axis=1)>10 and df.mean(axis=1)<2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use drop, but you can index... You also need to use `&` rather than `and`:

```
m = df.mean(axis=1)  # calculate once
df = df.loc[:, (m>10) & (m<2)]
```

Comment: your answer is correct but i think, axis=0 since i want to drop column instead. Thanks again

Comment: Actually, when i apply it to some dataFrame where some entries are nan, and some with unequal length, I have this error : Unalignable boolean Series key provided

Comment: @user3841581 did you try `df = df.loc[:, (m>10) & (m<2)]`. I think you're right about the axis, I just used your .mean method without reading it.