# IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided in linux

Tags: python, linux, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame and I would like to drop some columns based on the values of their mean. For eaxmple I have:

```
column 1  column 2   column 3
      1          1          3
      1          2          3
      2          1          4
```

I used [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851209/excluding-columns-from-a-dataframe-based-on-their-mean-without-using-a-loop/33852204?noredirect=1#comment55512758_33852204) which works fine on windows. For example, from the dataFrame df, i would like to drop columns that have a mean greater than 2.5 I wrote:

```
m=df.mean(axis=0)
df.loc[:,m<=2.5]
```

That works perfectly on Windows as the column 3 is dropped. But when I try it in linux, I have the following error:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided .
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Without a MWE it's difficult to tell... can you provide one?

Comment: Is your pandas version `pd.__version__` same on both machines?